# Why isn't gridview cells being reused?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using stickyheaders gridview with lots of images, and the header is text. At any given time I have between 10 and 20 images on the screen. I am using viewholder pattern to reuse the cells.

However, many times the cells are not reused - why? Furthermore, each cell is getting called twice - why?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Photo photo = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "convertview is null :"+position);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photo_grid, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.selected = convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "convertview is resused :"+position);
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    frameLoader.pauseOnFling(isFlinging);
    frameLoader.pauseOnScroll(isScrolling);
    frameLoader.setMaxItems(getVisiblePhotoCount());
    frameLoader.displaySmallImage(photo, viewHolder.imageView);
    if (mSelectedItems.contains(photo)) {
        viewHolder.selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
    else {
        viewHolder.selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is what the logoutput looks like:

[image]

Comment: How big is your screen and how many grid cells do you have? nr or columns x number of rows? Pls take into account that android might prepare a low number of grid cells to be displayed just before being used.

Comment: what is `frameLoader` and what is it doing?

Comment: loading images lazily - it doesnt not change the convertview, only the image inside it

Comment: number of columns = 4 number of rows that fit the screen 5

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` uses the view `recycler` to keep adding recycled views below or above the current viewport and moving active views to a `recyclable pool` as they move `off-screencode` while scrolling. This way GridView only needs to keep `enough views in memory` to fill its allocated space in the layout and some additional recyclable views—even when your adapter has hundreds of items. It will fill the space with rows in different ways—from top, from bottom, etc—depending on how the viewport. The image below visually summarizes what happens when you pan a GridView down.

[image]

In case no View is available for reuse, Android will pass null to the convertView parameter.